# conditional object inside fragment throwing error

Tags: thymeleaf

I have a main section that uses th:if with the same obj I'm using in my fragment but the fragment is throwing an error based on that obj.

Below, the nameInfo in mainInfo fragment is throwing an error. Even with null check.

// main.html

```
<section th:if="${nameInfo != null AND nameInfo.firstName != null}">
  <section class="main-cont">
    <div id="name-method>
       <div class="main-lg-3">
          <div th:replace="component/mainInfo :: mainInfo_check "></div>
       </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</section>
```

// mainInfo.html

```
<div th:fragment="mainInfo">
  <form>
     <section th:if="${nameInfo != null AND nameInfo.firstName != null}">
        <div class="radio_btn">
            <input type="radio" tabindex="0" onchange="test(0, val)" />
            <label for="test-rb" style="outline: none;">
                <span class="radio"></span>
                <span>Name</span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </section>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to show (a) the specific error message being thrown, and (b) the content of the `mainInfo_check` fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this

```
<div th:replace="component/mainInfo :: mainInfo_check "></div>
```

To this

```
<div th:replace="component/mainInfo :: mainInfo"></div>
```

Comment: that won't work because I'm rendering mainInfo_check depending on other conditions